# Image will not fade while using Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly simple line of code when matched up with the CSS, the clickable image which in this case is a logo, should fade when hovered over with the mouse. This seems to be working correctly on Edge, however when loading the page via Google Chrome, the fade effect will not work.

I have also tried a few variations, however I receive the same outcome.

This code probably isnt too helpful, but I decided to throw it in here anyways.

```
<?php echo "<a href='' class='logo_fade'><img src='" . $logo_source . "' height='" . $logo_height . "' width='" . $logo_width . "' style='padding-top:" . $logo_height_spacing . "px;'" . $logo_height_spacing . "'></a>";   ?>
```

CSS:

```
 a:link img {
  opacity: 1.0;
 }
 a:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Comment: try this `a img {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }
 a:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
 }`

Comment: Instead of giving the PHP code, you should load your page and copy the `<a>` element directly from the DOM so we can preview it here

Comment: i think instead of putting the :hover on a try putting it on img

Comment: With the code you provided, it still works perfectly on Edge. But no fade on chrome.